# how to pass array variable with data:JSON.stringify( {check:chkArray,exame_name:exame_name}),

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Am posting a data form  through ajax and i got a problem in passing array inside data:{....} can any solve my problem please.more over my questions denotes what am trying to do..

### main purpose

to append all the checked value into an array and i have to pass the array to a another page. along with a string value named exam_name and have to pass array value as json using ajax

### html

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>Spring Boot - AJAX POST GET Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="create_test" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="exame_name"id="exame_name"/>
    <div id="checkboxlist">
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk"> Value 1</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk"> Value 2</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk"> Value 3</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk"> Value 4</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="5" class="chk"> Value 5</div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Get Value Using Class" id="buttonClass">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

### jquery and ajax

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Get the checkboxes values based on the class attached to each check box */
    $("#buttonClass").click(function() {
        getValueUsingClass();
        
        ajaxPost();
    });
    
    
    
});

function getValueUsingClass(){
    /* declare an checkbox array */
    var chkArray = [];
    
    /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
    $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
        var checker=chkArray.push($(this).val());
    
    });
    var result=[];
    for(var i=0;i<length.chkArray;i++)
    {
      result[i]=chkArray[i];
    }
    
    /* we join the array separated by the comma */
    var selected;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') ;
    var exame_name=$("#exame_name").val();
    
    /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if(selected.length > 1){
        alert("You have selected " + chkArray);
        alert("exame_name "+exame_name);        
    }else{
        alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");   
    }
}
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data:JSON.stringify( {check:chkArray,exame_name:exame_name}),
   url: "index.php",
   success: function(msg){
     $('.answer').html(msg);
   }
});

    
    
 </script>
```

### question

I have to pass array value in ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var obj = { "check":"chkArray", "exame_name":"exame_name"};
```

Then in your ajax call

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Also you can directly pass json to stringify i.e. JSON.stringify({ "check":"chkArray", "exame_name":"exame_name"}); which will give you same result

Comment: okay sir still can u help me how to alert the obj before calling ajax can u please

Comment: add alert right after function  i.e. function getValueUsingClass() { alert(obj);